# Python create a thread for each item in dict

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a dict that is filled with key value pairs. Each value is a dict.
I have a for loop to iterate through all items in list. Then runs a function while passing it 3 args from the values of the item.

Atm it loops through every item in dict and completes 1 per time.

I'd like to have a way for my program to create a thread for every item in dict. Total amount of rows will not always be the same so I need a way for looping through while passing the args to the functions. With a limit of how many threads run at 1 time

Anyone able to help with some guidance?

Comment: The answer is almost never "manually make a thread for each and every item". I might suggest looking at `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` (both of which are pools of worker threads that work can be distributed between). The latter is a recently documented addition to the `multiprocessing` module (originally, it was only documented by side-effect when they mentioned the `multiprocessing.dummy` module, which provides the same API as `multiprocessing`, backed by threads instead of processes). Either one will limit how many threads run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing any I/O in this code, then threading is not going to help you AT ALL.  Python's Global Interpreter Lock means that only one thread can be running Python code at any given time.  The ONLY time threading helps in Python is when your threads are blocking for time, or waiting for a network operation, or some other I/O, or running C code like numpy.

Multiprocessing can help, as long as you're not updating a bunch of global data.  If you have well-defined inputs and output, it's worth a try.

Comment: This is true, but the OP hasn't given enough information to say whether they're in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This morning after a fresh sleep and took another look. I just had to format my format loop better to create thread for all in dict. Multi threading is helping the speed as the threads want for some external process before continuing. So they all fire off at the same time saving quite a bit. Instead of one fires, waits x sec. Then the next etc.